# VHDL Type Attribute

Tags: attributes, vhdl

I have found these lines in mathpack.vhd:

```
    constant TWO_AT_MINUS : REAL_VECTOR := POWER_OF_2_SERIES(
                                               NATURAL_VECTOR'(100, 90),1.0,
                                                                  MAX_ITER);
```

The signature of the POWER_OF_2_SERIES is in the same file:

```
    function POWER_OF_2_SERIES (D : in NATURAL_VECTOR; INITIAL_VALUE : in REAL;
                NUMBER_OF_VALUES : in NATURAL) return REAL_VECTOR is
```

So it's clear that NATURAL_VECTOR'(100, 90) produces a NATURAL_VECTOR, but how?I have never seen something like it and I can't find it in the LRM. Can anybody elaborate on this notation/where I can find it in the LRM?

Answer (score 0):

Found it... it is a qualified expression for an aggregate (LRM 7.3.4) defined as

```
qualified_expression ::=
type_mark ' ( expression )
| type_mark ' aggregate
```

and as choices are optional in an aggregate (LRM 7.3.2)

```
aggregate ::=
( element_association { , element_association } )
element_association ::=
[ choices => ] expression
```

this is simply a one dimensional array containing the two values 100 and 90 and as

```
type NATURAL_VECTOR is array (NATURAL range <>) of NATURAL;
```

I would assume that they are in 0 => 100 and 1 => 90, modelSim thinks so, too.

Comment: For the record, neither `MathPack.vhd` nor `natural_vector` are standard VHDL constructs and must be in your custom VHDL.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-1993  7.3.2.2 Array aggregates for the rules governing the index values.  7.3.4 Qualified expressions tells you there is a check that the aggregate expression (indexed 0 to 1) belongs to the subtype of the index type of NATURAL_VECTOR (it does) but performs no implicit subtype conversion. REAL_VECTOR isn't defined until -2008 and has a similar story elaborated of the constant doesn't involve a subtype conversion when unconstrained. Without seeing the definition of POWER_OF_2_SERIES no conclusion of it's index values can be made here. Provide a [mcve] in the question.